# what is the best way to read a template in xls and create a new file in xlsx using python

Tags: python, xls, xlsx, xlrd, xlsxwriter

I have a template with xls/xlsx file and I'm tring to create a new file using xlsxwriter, however I want to copy the template.

What is the best way to read the template of the xls/xlsx and create a new file?

The reason I am using the xlsxwriter is to fill the lines, and it passes the 655355 lines.

Answer (score 1):

Let's quote `xlsxwriter`s [FAQ](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html), as of April 19th, 2015

> Q. Can XlsxWriter use an existing Excel file as a template?
>
> No.
>
> XlsxWriter is designed only as a file writer. It cannot read or modify an existing Excel file.